# Python AGI script results in Asterisk error 510

Tags: python, dialogflow-es, asterisk, agi

I'm trying to intigrate google dialog flow with asterisk to use in one of my other agi chatbot scripts. However i ran into a problem when executing the script using asterisk. The script works fine when runned from command line but fails when runned trough asterisk, any idea why? i'm using base installed Python 2.7 on centos server. The script when running trough asterisk fails at line: session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()
(checked this by printing a number each lane and checking when error is thrown)

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import dialogflow
import sys
import json

def detect_intent_texts(project_id, session_id, texts, language_code):
    """Returns the result of detect intent with texts as inputs.

    Using the same `session_id` between requests allows continuation
    of the conversation."""

    import dialogflow_v2 as dialogflow
    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()

    session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)
    print('Session path: {}\n'.format(session))

    text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(
        text=texts, language_code=language_code)

    query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)

    response = session_client.detect_intent(
        session=session, query_input=query_input)

    print('=' * 20)
    print('Query text: {}'.format(response.query_result.query_text))
    print('Detected intent: {} (confidence: {})\n'.format(
        response.query_result.intent.display_name,
        response.query_result.intent_detection_confidence))
    print('Fulfillment text: {}\n'.format(
        response.query_result.fulfillment_text))
try:
  detect_intent_texts("fake-219706", 34, "hallo dit is nick vaes","nl")
except:
  print("error")
```

Output when runned on command line:

```
[root@stage-ai agi-bin]# ./DF.py
Session path: projects/fake-219706/agent/sessions/34

====================
Query text: hallo dit is nick vaes
Detected intent: Default Welcome Intent (confidence: 1.0)

Fulfillment text: Goedemorgen zoekt u een groep of een persoon?
```

Asterisk output:

```
Connected to Asterisk 16.2.1 currently running on stage-ai (pid = 3600)
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Executing [*9@INTERNO:1] NoOp("SIP/6004-0000003a", "called *9") in new stack
    -- Executing [*9@INTERNO:2] Answer("SIP/6004-0000003a", "") in new stack
    -- Executing [*9@INTERNO:3] Verbose("SIP/6004-0000003a", "the caller is: 6004") in new stack
the caller is: 6004
    -- Executing [*9@INTERNO:4] Set("SIP/6004-0000003a", "caller=6004") in new stack
    -- Executing [*9@INTERNO:5] AGI("SIP/6004-0000003a", "DF.py") in new stack
    -- Launched AGI Script /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/DF.py
<SIP/6004-0000003a>AGI Tx >> agi_request: DF.py
<SIP/6004-0000003a>AGI Tx >> agi_channel: SIP/6004-0000003a
<SIP/6004-0000003a>AGI Tx >> agi_language: en
<SIP/6004-0000003a>AGI Tx >> agi_type: SIP
<SIP/6004-0000003a>AGI Tx >> agi_uniqueid: 1554996754.116
<SIP/6004-0000003a>AGI Tx >> agi_version: 16.2.1
<SIP/6004-0000003a>AGI Tx >> agi_callerid: 6004
<SIP/6004-0000003a>AGI Tx >> agi_calleridname: Yannick
<SIP/6004-0000003a>AGI Tx >> agi_callingpres: 0
<SIP/6004-0000003a>AGI Tx >> agi_callingani2: 0
<SIP/6004-0000003a>AGI Tx >> agi_callington: 0
<SIP/6004-0000003a>AGI Tx >> agi_callingtns: 0
<SIP/6004-0000003a>AGI Tx >> agi_dnid: *9
<SIP/6004-0000003a>AGI Tx >> agi_rdnis: unknown
<SIP/6004-0000003a>AGI Tx >> agi_context: INTERNO
<SIP/6004-0000003a>AGI Tx >> agi_extension: *9
<SIP/6004-0000003a>AGI Tx >> agi_priority: 5
<SIP/6004-0000003a>AGI Tx >> agi_enhanced: 0.0
<SIP/6004-0000003a>AGI Tx >> agi_accountcode:
<SIP/6004-0000003a>AGI Tx >> agi_threadid: 140598249563904
<SIP/6004-0000003a>AGI Tx >>
<SIP/6004-0000003a>AGI Rx << error
<SIP/6004-0000003a>AGI Tx >> 510 Invalid or unknown command
    -- <SIP/6004-0000003a>AGI Script DF.py completed, returning 0
    -- Executing [*9@INTERNO:6] Hangup("SIP/6004-0000003a", "") in new stack
  == Spawn extension (INTERNO, *9, 6) exited non-zero on 'SIP/6004-0000003a'
stage-ai*CLI>
```

DialPlan:

```
exten => *9,1,NoOp(called *9)
same => n,Answer()
same => n,agi(DF.py)
```

Comment: This is not an AGI script. Nowhere are you outputting anything that is an AGI command.

Comment: you are correct this is a python script for now, i took out the code that made my AGI script fail, but the script still gives output that shows up in asterisk AGI debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script at some point print word "error" into STDOUT.

Asterisk AGI specification have no "error" command, so it say you about error.

Code like this is VERY bad practice, becuase you not know which exception you got.

```
except:
  print("error")
```

Comment: i know this is a bad practice, this was purely done to check if my script crashed or something else was going wrong.

Comment: Okay,so your script crashed. Whats now?

Comment: my script crashed running trough asterisk, the script on itselfs runs perfectly.

Comment: So you want me guess why your script crashed? Do some more small work, write correctly which exception you get and you will know.

Comment: I bet this problem related to general code practices and api params, not asterisk itself.

Comment: you're right, the script fails because for some reason it can't determine the google credentials automatically,